# Как получить разрешения для редактирования настроек в возможностях

Tags: wordpress, header

Через [image]

[image: Не могу поменять логотип через настройки шаблона для главной страницы]
Появляется ошибка о том, что "нет разрешения для изменения настроек в возможностях", хотя редактирую через учетку админа. Как получить эти разрешения?

[image: при нажатии на кнопку опубликовать появляется ошибка "не удается сохранить из-за 115 неверных настроек"]
Откуда появилось столько ошибок и как их можно исправить?
Как сохранить новый логотип?

Comment: Какая у вас роль на сайте? Не хватает прав на редактирование

Comment: Или кривая тема (что вряд ли) или ты не админ. Проварить легко - если настройки ВП не доступны значит ты не админ